# How to get the response from ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, response

Here is the code for sending request to api to create users and save them into MySQL.

```
signUp.Click += async (s,e) =>
        {
            string name = uName.Text;
            string pin = pWord.Text;
            string rePin = rePWord.Text;
            string em = email.Text;
            string encoded="";

            if ((name != "") && (pin != "") && (rePin != "") && (em != ""))
            {
                if (pin.Equals(rePin))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string orig = pin;

                        byte[] salt;
                        new RNGCryptoServiceProvider().GetBytes(salt = new byte[16]);

                        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(orig, salt, 10000);

                        byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
                        byte[] hashBytes = new byte[36];

                        Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, 16);
                        Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, 16, 20);

                        encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

                        Console.WriteLine(encoded);

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Encode errors.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The password doesn't match");
                }
                var response = await RunPostAsync(name, encoded, em).ConfigureAwait(false);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Some value are missing");
            }


        };
```

This is the code for RunPostAsync method.

```
public async Task<Person> RunPostAsync(string name, string pword, string email)
{

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var RestUrl = "http://10.20.1.68:45455/api/Person/";
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, RestUrl);

        var p = new Person();

        p.name = name;
        p.password = pword;
        p.email = email;

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p);
        request.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        return p;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the code in my API In here, it checks if the username, which revived from client, exists in the table. If the name already exist, return the string"The user is already exsit!", otherwise, create new user and return string "Added!".

```
// POST: api/Person
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]Person person)
{
    string postReult;
    ArrayList unameList = new ArrayList();
    ConnectMysql();
    string checkString = "SELECT uname FROM users";

    MySqlCommand checkCmd = new MySqlCommand(checkString, conn);

    MySqlDataReader myReader = checkCmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        string pname = myReader["uname"].ToString();

        unameList.Add(pname);
    }
    myReader.Close();

    if (!unameList.Contains(person.name))
    {
        string queryString = "INSERT INTO `users` (`uname`, `pword`, `email`) VALUES ('" + person.name + "', '" + person.password + "', '" + person.email + "');";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryString, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        postReult = "Added!";
    }
    else
    {
        postReult = "The user is already exsit!";
    }
    return postReult;
}
```

My question is how can I get the different returned string "Added!" or "The user is already exsit!" as the response from API to client?